# Create sticker set from a sent image

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram, python-telegram-bot

I am trying to create a sticker set using images that are sent by a user to my bot. I have the following code:

```
MY_USER_ID = "MyFakeUserId"
MY_TOKEN = "MyFakeToken"
import logging
logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s', level=logging.INFO)

from telegram.ext import Updater, MessageHandler, Filters, CommandHandler

updater = Updater(token=MY_TOKEN, use_context=True)
updater.start_polling()

dispatcher = updater.dispatcher

def create_sticker_set(update, context):

    update_dict = update.to_dict()

    sticker_file_id = update_dict["message"]["photo"][-1]["file_id"]

    print("sticker_file_id=", sticker_file_id)
    # sticker_file = context.bot.upload_sticker_file(MY_USER_ID, sticker_file_id)

    context.bot.create_new_sticker_set(MY_USER_ID, "lala_by_my_fake_bot", "lala", sticker_file_id, "")

msghandler = MessageHandler(Filters.photo, create_sticker_set)
dispatcher.add_handler(msghandler)
```

I send to chat a png picture that has size exactly 512px x 512px. And this code doesn't work.

I get the following message in my logs:

```
sticker_file_id= AgACAgQAAx0CUsT2sgADyF5SvWsoQ9ZTjw436M0nntrlkUtkAALjsTEb9W2ZUg-6JVL7B5D8wjq2GwAEAQADAgADeAADyYoDAAEYBA
2020-02-23 18:59:07,376 - telegram.ext.dispatcher - ERROR - No error handlers are registered, logging exception.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/telegram/ext/dispatcher.py", line 390, in process_update
    handler.handle_update(update, self, check, context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/telegram/ext/handler.py", line 117, in handle_update
    return self.callback(update, context)
  File "testing.py", line 58, in callback
    context.bot.create_new_sticker_set(MY_USER_ID, "facebooklala_by_ibodi_bot", "FacebookLala", sticker_file_id, "")
  File "</usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/decorator.py:decorator-gen-58>", line 2, in create_new_sticker_set
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/telegram/bot.py", line 67, in decorator
    result = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/telegram/bot.py", line 3298, in create_new_sticker_set
    result = self._request.post(url, data, timeout=timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/telegram/utils/request.py", line 334, in post
    **urlopen_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/telegram/utils/request.py", line 245, in _request_wrapper
    raise BadRequest(message)
telegram.error.BadRequest: Type of file mismatch
```

I don't see another way out apart from downloading the picture and then reuploading it. Like this:

```
def create_sticker_set(update, context):

    update_dict = update.to_dict()

    sticker_file_id = update_dict["message"]["photo"][-1]["file_id"]

    print("sticker_file_id=", sticker_file_id)
    # sticker_file = context.bot.upload_sticker_file(MY_USER_ID, sticker_file_id)

    file = context.bot.get_file(update_dict["message"]["photo"][-1]["file_id"])
    filename = file.download()

    context.bot.create_new_sticker_set(MY_USER_ID, "lala_by_ibodi_bot", "lala", open(filename, "rb"), "")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. Uploading png files as photos and not files converts this file to jpg. `sticker_file_id` was not the right argument to `context.bot.create_new_sticker_set`, because it was `file_id` of jpg file, and it should've been `file_id` of png file.

This code should work under the condition that we upload pictures as files and not photos.

```
MY_USER_ID = "MyFakeUserId"
MY_TOKEN = "MyFakeToken"
import logging
logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s', level=logging.INFO)

from telegram.ext import Updater, MessageHandler, Filters, CommandHandler

updater = Updater(token=MY_TOKEN, use_context=True)
updater.start_polling()

dispatcher = updater.dispatcher

def create_sticker_set(update, context):

    update_dict = update.to_dict()

    sticker_file_id = update_dict["message"]["document"]["file_id"]

    print("sticker_file_id=", sticker_file_id)
    # sticker_file = context.bot.upload_sticker_file(MY_USER_ID, sticker_file_id)

    context.bot.create_new_sticker_set(MY_USER_ID, "lala_by_my_fake_bot", "lala", sticker_file_id, "")

msghandler = MessageHandler(Filters.document, create_sticker_set)
dispatcher.add_handler(msghandler)
```